# Is there currently a plugin for PhoneGap and Windows Phone to make an application with a QR code scanner?

Tags: cordova, cross-platform, barcode-scanner, windows-phone

I have looked everywhere and it seems that it is currently not possible to make a QR scanning application for Windows Phone using PhoneGap. I know that plugins exist for iOS, Android and Blackberry, however it seems the WP plugin is non-existent.

That being said, I know that there is C# code that can decode a QR code, however I am not sure if I can use it since we will be developing the app using PhoneGap (thus HTML5, CSS and Javascript.)  Therefore, is there a PhoneGap plugin for reading QR Codes with Windows Phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, unfortunately not.

You'd be more than welcome to contribute one, there's a quick guide on how to get started with creating plugins for Phonegap on Windows Phone here: http://www.risingj.com/archives/92

Answer (score 0):

There is now plugin Barcode Scanner for windows Phone
https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/WindowsPhone/BarcodeScanner

Free for use.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work. Documentation and support is also poor for it.